# Doubles of NetworkRequestMetric in Logcat for each network query

Tags: android, networking, okhttp, firebase-performance

I am using Firebase Performance in my Android application and see the doubles of each network query in Logcat. Here is an example:

```
2019-04-09 19:19:18.206 25147-28713/com.example.app D/OkHttp: --> GET https://my-host.net/getStatistic?
19:19:18.273 25147-28713/com.example.app D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://my-host.net/getStatistic? (66ms)
2019-04-09 19:19:18.282 25147-25252/com.example.app D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic 0b 76ms,
2019-04-09 19:19:18.284 25147-25252/com.example.app I/FirebasePerformance: Rate Limited NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic
2019-04-09 19:19:18.285 25147-25252/com.example.app D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic 0b 111ms,
2019-04-09 19:19:18.286 25147-25252/com.example.app I/FirebasePerformance: Rate Limited NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic
2019-04-09 19:19:24.770 25147-25147/com.example.app I/InfoManager.lambda$getStatisticsDisposable$0,208: StatisticData :
```

`OkHttp` interceptor is showing only one request in logcat. But there are two lines of "Logging NetworkRequestMetric" of `FirebasePerformance` with different time metrics. I also have `Stetho` incorporated in the app, and `Stetho` also shows only one request is made to the server.

So, why is the `FirebasePerformance` showing that the request is made twice?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the log - it seems the two network requests were made are captured. One important thing to note here is that the logs do not show the complete URL, the queryParams are stripped before logging. So the domain and query path might be the same, but the params might be different.

2019-04-09 19:19:18.282 25147-25252/com.example.app D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic 0b 76ms,
2019-04-09 19:19:18.284 25147-25252/com.example.app I/FirebasePerformance: Rate Limited NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic
2019-04-09 19:19:18.285 25147-25252/com.example.app D/FirebasePerformance: Logging NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic 0b 111ms,
2019-04-09 19:19:18.286 25147-25252/com.example.app I/FirebasePerformance: Rate Limited NetworkRequestMetric - https://my-host.net/getStatistic